# How to keep NSWindow.FrameAutosaveName out of scope of tabbed windows?

Tags: swift, tabs, nswindow, appkit, nswindowcontroller

I have a `NSWindowController`class in an app that can be used to show a standalone window or to show a tabbed window attached to a main window, which has a different window controller. If the user opens the window as standalone, then I want to use the same window position and size as the last standalone window session. It's comparable to opening a code view in Xcode in a new window.

So I have a `self.windowFrameAutosaveName = NSWindow.FrameAutosaveName("Detail App Window")` line in `windowDidLoad`. This works, but the problem is that it also works when the window is shown as a tab in the main window. Next time the user opens the same window as standalone, the size of the main window is being used.

**Question**: how can I keep `self.windowFrameAutosaveName` outside a tabbed window scenario?

I create the window controller like this:

```
let storyboard = NSStoryboard(name: "Detail", bundle: nil)

if let controller = storyboard.instantiateInitialController() as? DetailController {
    document.addWindowController(controller)

    if tabbed, 
        let mainWindow = document.windowControllers.first?.window, 
        let detailWindow = controller.window {
        mainWindow.addTabbedWindow(detailWindow, ordered: .above)
    }
    else {
        controller.showWindow(nil)
    }
}
```

The code in `windowDidLoad` of the *DetailController* above is:

```
override func windowDidLoad() {
    super.windowDidLoad()    
    self.shouldCascadeWindows = true
    self.windowFrameAutosaveName = NSWindow.FrameAutosaveName("Detail App Window")
}
```

As you see, I use `self.shouldCascadeWindows = true`, and this must also keep working. I have experimented with detecting being in a tab scenario, but without any complete success. Also, moving the `windowFrameAutosaveName` before the `controller.showWindow(nil)` works in itself, but the windows are no longer loaded with `shouldCascadeWindows = true`.

Interesting, even Xcode doesn't do that, so maybe it's a limitation of AppKit.

Comment: How do you create the windows?

Comment: @Willeke I have added some code to the question

Comment: Can't you set `windowFrameAutosaveName` before `showWindow`? Setting `shouldCascadeWindows` in `windowDidLoad` is too late. See [Document-Based App autosave with storyboards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35827239/document-based-app-autosave-with-storyboards/43726191#43726191).

Comment: @Willeke Yes, I can do that, but that doesn't work together with shouldCascadeWindows, see last remarks in my question. Setting shouldCascadeWindows to true in windowDidLoad does work in my case, if I leave it out then windows are not cascaded. Moving it to another sport doesn't change anything or just don't work.

Comment: Do you want to restore the frame from user defaults or do you want to cascade the window?

Comment: @Willeke Both. But user defaults must not be updated with the window frame size when loaded as tab.

Comment: Which window should appear where and which window's location should be stored in the user defaults?